# Get count of value for 15 min periods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with a `DateTimeIndex`. I would like to get the `count` of all different (integer) values for column `col1` for each 15 min period.

I have looked at `groupby` and `count` but this doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('15Min')['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: 15M means 15 months, I think you meant to use '15Min'